# Openvas Erroneous or missing signature for checksums file (null)

Tags: openvas

My exp.nasl

```
insstr("aaaaaaaaaaa", "bb", 3, 0xfffffffd);
```

run code

```
$sudo openvas-nasl ali.nasl
```

I get this error when I run exp.nasl with openvas

```
base gpgme-Message: Setting GnuPG dir to '/etc/openvas/gnupg'
base gpgme-Message: Using OpenPGP engine version '2.1.11'
Erroneous or missing signature for checksums file (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `-X` flag to `openvas-nasl` if you don't have a valid signature for your file:

```
openvas-nasl -X ali.nasl
```

See `openvas-nasl --help` and/or `man openvas-nasl` for a description of this and other existing flags.